# API Google Drive Java

Tags: java, netbeans, api, google-drive

quisiera saber si se puede realizar una conexión a Google Drive con mi aplicación de escritorio, tengo realizado un programa de ventas y lo que quiero hacer es tener un botón que al darle click descargue el reporte de las ventas totales y ese mismo archivo se suba a google drive automáticamente, ya tengo hecho los reportes, solo quiero hacer que se suba en automático a Google Drive, realmente no se si se pueda, es una idea que surgió de un de repente en mi cabeza, les agradecería bastante si me pudieras explicar si se puede

Comment: Todo es posible en esta vida, el primer paso es intentarlo. [Te he votado negativamente porque sin código, es difícil ayudarte](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2875/)

Comment: Favor de no usar [google]. Ya se ha eliminado del sitio en varias ocasiones y se ha realizado una solicitud de que se ponga en la lista negra. Ref. [¿Necesitamos \[google\]?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1030/65) y [¿Algún “malvado” que ponga a \[google\] en la lista negra?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2684/65)

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro : Seamos cordiales y evitemos comentarios como "Te he votado negativamente" sobre todo si no se ha votado así. Por otro lado no es obligatorio que todas las preguntas incluyan código.

Comment: Ok entonces [Te he votado negativamente porque hacer una investigación previa es necesario para realizar una buena pregunta.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878)

Comment: Yo tengo un ejemplo de subida de archivo usando la api Google Drive , pero usando servlet , te lo comparto haber si te ayuda , te lo dejo [aqui](https://github.com/jsdominguez/Google-Drive-Api-Java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claro que si, Google cuenta con API's con la posibilidad de comunicarte a un web service (REST). Ya depende de ti como lo quieras aplicar en tu aplicacion. Te comparto su url, en el se adjuntan algunos ejemplos. Saludos

> https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java